# Loops repeats twice

Tags: php, loops, do-while

```
$n = 0;
do {
    echo "START PAGE\n";
    echo "total pages: " . $response->PaginationResult->TotalNumberOfPages . "\n";
    echo "current page: " . $currentPage . "\n";
    echo "iteration: " . $n;
    if ($n == 2) {
        break;
    }

    $j = 0;
    foreach($response->SaleRecord as $SaleRecord) {

        if ($j == 2) {
            break;
        }

        echo "\n\tSTART RECORD";

        foreach($SaleRecord->SellingManagerSoldTransaction as $transaction) {
            echo "\n\t\tRECORD INNER";
            foreach($getOrders->OrderArray->Order as $orders) {
                echo "\n\t\t\tGETORDERS - " . $itemID;
                foreach($orders->TransactionArray->Transaction as $transaction) {
                    echo "\n\t\t\t\tTXN ARRAY - " . $itemID;
                }
            }
        }

        $j++;
        echo "\n\tEND RECORD";
    }

    $n++;
    $currentPage+= 1;
    echo "\nEND PAGE\n\n\n";
}

while (isset($response->SaleRecord) && $currentPage <= $response->PaginationResult->TotalNumberOfPages);
```

OUTPUT:

```
START PAGE
total pages: 231
current page: 1
iteration: 0
    START RECORD
        RECORD INNER
            GETORDERS - 997
                TXN ARRAY - 997
    END RECORD
    START RECORD
        RECORD INNER
            GETORDERS - 998
                TXN ARRAY - 998
            GETORDERS - 998
                TXN ARRAY - 998
    END RECORD
END PAGE


START PAGE
total pages: 231
current page: 2
iteration: 1
    START RECORD
        RECORD INNER
            GETORDERS - 997
                TXN ARRAY - 997
            GETORDERS - 997
                TXN ARRAY - 997
    END RECORD
    START RECORD
        RECORD INNER
            GETORDERS - 998
                TXN ARRAY - 998
            GETORDERS - 998
                TXN ARRAY - 998
    END RECORD
END PAGE

START PAGE
total pages: 231
current page: 3
iteration: 2
```

Spent hours on this but can't figure out why the loop runs multiple times, even the inner loops! I must be doing something very silly, just can't find what and where.

Comment: you should use while instead do while because that check condition after iteration is over

Comment: If you want to execute the code only once, why do you have a do while loop?

Comment: Even if I repalce the `do-while` with just `while` the output is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $n = 0 and your break condition is $n == 2, that's 2 iterations: $n = 0 and $n = 1

Same thing for $j.

Change your conditions to $n == 1 and $j == 1 (or $n < 2 and $j < 2)

Answer (score 0):

He breaks when n equals 2. You start with n = 0 (first loop) and then it becomes n = 1 (second loop) Then it breaks when n == 2 (third loop). You should change the break block to the following and then it works:

```
if ($n == 1) {
    break;
}
```